# How can i share an image and a message on instagram and receive feedback whether it was shared or not on a react-native mobile app?

Tags: react-native, expo, instagram, react-native-share

I want to share an image and some text on instagram and should be able to know wether i shared successfully or not,maybe have something like a callback that indicates that. I tried [react-native-share](https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share) but have found certain issues with it which are

1. [react-native-share](https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share) does not show wether the shared media was successful or not,it only  shows an attempt to share.
2. For some reason when sharing on instagram,it does not share both text and media, it only shares one.